# Where to learn Français with certification?

Tags: online-learning, french

Bonjour,

I want to learn Français because my [Université](https://doctorat.campusfrance.org/ED130) requires B2 level Français, I have done a ton of searches and found the following details:

Language Levels

```
A1, A2 - DILF
B1, B2 - DELF
C1, C2 - DALF
```

Hence I need to learn upto `DELF` level Français, now I found a website [rocketlanguages.com](https://www.rocketlanguages.com) which offers a `Level 1,2,3` combo for `$259.90` which is a good enough deal.

My question: If I buy that course will my [Université](https://doctorat.campusfrance.org/ED130) recognize their certificate? if not then please suggest me a website who actually will provide me `DELF` level certificate.

Comment: Where are you located?

Comment: @Lambie I’m from India.

Comment: Well, they are all over the place but not sure one is near you. You can check here: http://www.cours.fr/cours-3-p2-en-inde44.html :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most well known institution is L'alliance française (FIAF)

They give the language level exams and have tons of classes at their sites around the world and online.

> Adults • Online French Courses Fall Session: Now–December 10 Online
> classes are HyFlex! Students on Zoom will engage with their teacher
> and classmates who are present in person at FIAF. Learn More
>
> Choose proficiency levels and course types to narrow search.

[French classes at the FIAF](https://fiaf.org/frenchclasses/)

They are recognized by all French universities.

[fiaf.org](https://fiaf.org/exams/)

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be applying to Sorbonne Université, based on the link, and to a doctoral program in informatics, telecommunications and electronics. The link also has contact information for the secretary.

You should contact the secretary and ask, rather than asking random people on the internet. Also, I would advise you to read the websites of the institution itself carefully; maybe they tell something about the language requirements.

Based on the website https://www.campusfrance.org/en/FAQ-Doctorate-France-questions it might be possible to work in English in your field, but this is not guaranteed; please ask the institution in question and, if you have a doctoral advisor in mind, them. Doctoral studies mean that you will be a co-worker, not just a student, so the expectations are different and might vary a lot based on your advisor.

Comment: I have met doctoral students and postdocs employed in France who could not speak French.

Comment: Yes, and I went to the Sorbonne and I took those tests. The OP didn't say anything about a Phd...

Comment: The website https://doctorat.campusfrance.org/ED130 seems to be most focused on doctoral studies, but maybe I misunderstand.

Comment: The OP does not mention doing a doctorate. Why do you keep insisting on it? Also, these are standard tests. Why are you arguing with me?

Comment: The OP links to a website aimed mostly towards doctoral studies and that even mentions writing one's thesis in English, so it seems natural to assume they are interested in doctoral studies. I am responding to your comments on my answer.

Comment: The website clearly states this:" **Niveau de français requis B2**
Niveau d'anglais requis B1
 Possibilité de rédiger sa thèse en anglais
 Anglais langue de travail possible
 Enseignement méthodologique en anglais
 Séminaires, cours, conférences en anglais//So, you can write your thesis in English but you have to know French. It could not be stated more clearly. And the OP wants to know where to get that certificate which I have told him. Your answer is not helpful at all.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Please feel free to downvote my answer; that is the way one signals it is not helpful at all.